# Method GetUserPhotosRequest for file_reference

Tags: python-3.x, api, telegram, telethon

I try get file_file_reference, but can't decode result

```
with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        result = client(functions.photos.GetUserPhotosRequest(
            user_id='******',
            offset=0,
            max_id=0,
            limit=0
        ))

        array_of_photos = result.photos
        for photo in array_of_photos:
            usert_photo = photo.file_reference
            print(usert_photo.decode('utf-8'))
```

Result:

```
b'\x00_F\x1a:\xc6\x1e\x9e\xc0\xd9\x18\x95\xff\x02\x01r\xff8d\xf2\xb9'
b"\x00_F\x18\xb6\xd51\xba\x1ek\x17\x0c\xc6I\x15\x96\xb4\x89\xb3\xa6'"
b'\x00_F\x18\xa6\xc0\xf72*FN\xe0|\x11\x9f+M\xfe\xe8Ab'
```

Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 7: invalid start byte
```

Comment: The result is in bytes and is not supposed to be converted to readable characters.

Comment: As [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593509/method-getuserphotosrequest-for-file-reference#comment112453599_63593583), `file_reference` is *not* enough to be able to download a photo, for anyone wondering.

Answer (score 0):

That reference can't be decoded to string, and shall be stored as bytes.

Comment: How to use this string to get a reference photo?

Comment: You have to save `id`, `hash` and `file_reference` to construct `InputPhoto`. reference: https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/input_photo.html